# python3 asyncio run_in_executor не завершает порождаемый поток после выполнения

Tags: python-3.x, asyncio

При работе следующего кода(набросан максимально тестовый и небольшой пример), после завершения работы метода *block_func* не завершается поток в котором выполнялся метод.

```
def block_func():
    i = 1


async def starter():
    future = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(
        executor=None,
        func=functools.partial(block_func)
    )

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.ensure_future(starter())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Не помогает даже вариант с очисткой тасков:

```
def block_func():
    i = 1


async def starter():
    future = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(
        executor=None,
        func=functools.partial(block_func)
    )

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def cleaner():
    while True:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            try:
                if task.exception() or task.done():
                    asyncio.Task._all_tasks.remove(task)
            except asyncio.futures.CancelledError:
                asyncio.Task._all_tasks.remove(task)
            except asyncio.futures.InvalidStateError:
                pass
        # :TODO: Чистим последний таск, иначе не возбуждаются ошибки из корутины
        task = None
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


asyncio.ensure_future(starter())
asyncio.ensure_future(cleaner())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Пробовал подставлять executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(), в таком случае получается завершать поток, путем вызова у future метода result, для вычитывания результата работы метода block_func в потоке.

Но данное решение мне не нравится, хочется разобраться почему поток не завершается сам по себе когда заканчивается выполнение метода внутри потока.

Comment: Что значит "не завершается поток"? Как вы это определяете?

Comment: Через htop смотрю за потоками порожденными main потоком, и после отработки корутины и удаления её Task-а, поток отсается висеть до завершения main потока программы. В executore также увиличивается кол-во потоков, но после отработки они оттуда не вычищаются.

Comment: Это логично, ведь цикл событий использует ThreadPoolExecutor, а он, как и следует из названия, переиспользует потоки, возвращая отработавшие в пул.

Comment: Да действительно, потоки переиспользуются, спасибо вам. Это очнь полезная информация.

Answer (score 0):

Когда поток завершится, то все данные внутри него скушает GC. В том числе и ответ.

Можно сделать чтоб поток завершался сам если ответ вам не нужен.

Просто повесьте пустую функцию на колбэк:

```
def cb(future):
    pass

future.add_done_callback(cb)
```

В колбэке можно обработать исключения:

```
def cb(future):
    exc = future.exception()
    if exc:
        logger.error(exc)
```